# Magento2 : PayPal Standard error "Express Checkout has been canceled"

Tags: magento2, error, payment-methods, paypal-express, paypal-standard

I am using Magento2.2.0 and I have enabled Payments Standard(Accept credit card and PayPal payments securely) and set up **paypal email** , **API username** , **API password**, **API Signature** etc.

Now on frontend when I am placing an order with PayPal standard, it is being redirected to PayPal page and if I complete the full Payment Process it is working fine.

But If I **cancelled** the payment, it is redirected to Shopping Cart Page with the message **"Express Checkout has been canceled"**.

Now my question is I have set up **PayPal Standard** but why it is giving error **"Express Checkout has been canceled"**.

Answer (score 0):

> Express Checkout has been canceled

is coming from

`Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\AbstractExpress\Cancel`

Both express checkout and Standard methods, the cancel url's class is extended from this class:

You will find that class extends by

> - Magento\Paypal\Controller\Payflowexpress\Cancel
> - Magento\Paypal\Controller\Expres\Cancel

Comment: So, the standard method is being used. It just the message coming the common class. Am I right ?

Comment: Idea ,says that .One of that those  class used for cancel url for paypal standard method `

        Magento\Paypal\Controller\Payflowexpress\Cancel
        Magento\Paypal\Controller\Expres\Cancel`

Answer (score 0):

Paypal provides two business solutions [Paypal Payment Solutions](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/compare-business-products).

1. PayPal Payments Standard
2. PayPal Payments Pro

Here in **Magento 2**, PayPal is configured to use [**Express Checkout API**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/#)

For the error message, you got as @Amit said the message is coming from the common class.

Yes, this is quite confusing ***naming issue***. You can read more from the [github issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2447)